# store integers from a for loop in a global array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to store integers from a for loop in a local function to a global array, is this possible? what I have now is:

```
int num[] = {0};
int Num[] = {0};
void convert(string text, string key)
{
for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
{
    char x = text.at(i);
    num[i] += int(x) - 97;
    cout << num[i] << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
{
    char y = key.at(i);
    Num[i] += int(y) - 97;
    cout << Num[i] << endl;
}}
```

how can I store the outputs from the for loop to the global arrays?

Comment: ::global_var[i]+=int(x)-97 ;//add inside for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are initializing arrays with size of one int and to get the same size of the string you'll need to use vector (dynamic array) instead of a normal array. Then you'll use resize methods on each vector and put there the length of each string, to have the same size. (Google: vector c++; learn about this awesome class because you'll use it more in a near future)

```
vector<int> num;
vector<int> Num;
void convert(string text, string key) 
{ 
    Num.resize(key.length());
    num.resize(text.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) 
    { 
         char x = text.at(i); 
         num[i] += int(x) - 97; 
         cout << num[i] << endl;
     } 

     for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)  
     { 
          char y = key.at(i);
          Num[i] += int(y) - 97; 
          cout << Num[i] << endl; 
      }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Always here for you.